# How to delete all the files which are not created today

Tags: linux, files, find, date, rm

I want to `delete all` the files in a folder which are not created today.
I know how to get the list of files which are created today using

```
find . -type f -mtime -1
```

But, I am not getting how to get the list of all files which are not created today.
Basically I have to find if there are files with old timestamp except today in a folder. If present I have to delete only the old files.

Comment: Linux only keeps creation times for `ext4` and `btrfs` as far as I know. `-mtime` gives the last time that the file was modified in any way including the contents, ownership, permissions, and name changes so neither your command nor those in the answers will delete files which weren't created today. It will delete files which weren't modified today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
find . -type f -mtime +0 -exec rm -f {} +
```

or

```
find . -type f ! -mtime -1 -exec rm -f {} +
```

Would remove the regular files whose content has been last modified more than 24 hours ago (`-mtime +0` meaning: whose *age* in days (rounded down to an integer, days are 24 hours, or 86400 Unix epoch second duration) is strictly greater than 0).

Some `find` implementations have a `-delete` predicate which you can use in place of `-exec rm -f {} +` which would make it safer and more efficient.

For files that have been last modified earlier than today 00:00:00, with GNU `find`, you can add the `-daystart` predicate. That will include the files that were last modified yesterday even if less than 24 hours ago.

With some `find` implementations, you can also do:

```
find . ! -newermt 00:00:00 -delete
```

To delete files that have been last modified before (or at exactly) 00:00:00 today.

Comment: Better use `find . -type f  !  -mtime -1 -print | xargs rm -f` if there are many such files.

Comment: @vonbrand, no, that has no benefit here  over the `-exec {} +` syntax and breaks for file paths that contain blanks or newlines or quotes or backslash.

Answer (score 1):

Using zsh, either natively or via `zsh -c "..."`:

```
rm -f /path/to/folder/*(.m+0)     # for that directory only

rm -f /path/to/folder/**/*(.m+0)  # recursively
```

The parens `(` ... `)` creates a [zsh "glob qualifier"](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-globbing_002c-qualifiers). Inside there, a dot `.` specifies plain files (similar to find's `-type f`) and the `m+0` requires that the file have a modification time that is strictly more than zero days ago, after truncating down to whole days — 23 hours is 0 days; 25 hours would be 1 day.

To even more closely match `find`'s default behavior of finding/matching "hidden" files (that start with a dot), add the capital D qualifier:

```
rm -f /path/to/folder/*(D.m+0)     # for that directory only

rm -f /path/to/folder/**/*(D.m+0)  # recursively
```

Comment: Like for `find -mtime +1`, `*(m+1)` is for files whose age in days (rounded down) is *strictly* greater than 1 (so 2 or more, 48 hours or more). You need  `*(.m+0)` for  files at least 24 hour old (`find -mtime +0`). `*(D.m+0)` to also include hidden ones like `find` does. Some `find` implementations have an alternative syntax: `find -mtime +1d` that is based on exact times.

Comment: It can be confusing, but the idea is that time is split into one-day chunks. `*(m0)` is the files modified between 1 day ago and now. `*(m1)` for the ones between 2 days ago and 1 day ago. `*(m+1)` is for files older than 2 days ago. Like for `find`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, Stéphane! My tests were too coarse to catch the difference. Still forcing myself to become familiar with zsh!

Comment: Ahhh, I see -- the explicit `d`ay qualifier would have to come right after the `m` (or `a` or `c`). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

find has the parameter `-not` or `!` which negates the one after and `-delete` to delete the files:

`find . ! -mtime -1 -type f -delete`

Note that `-not` is not POSIX compliant

Comment: `-delete` is not POSIX either.

Answer (score 0):

When the number of old files than a day is of large amount, I do the below just to be thorough.
Get the number of files per day:

```bsh
$ find . -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td\n' | sort | uniq -c
# Output:
  42315 2020-09-29
  42315 2020-09-30
  42315 2020-10-01
  42315 2020-10-02
  42315 2020-10-03
  42315 2020-10-04
  42315 2020-10-05
   2275 2020-10-06
```

And to delete all files older than current day:

```bsh
$ find . -mindepth 1 -type f -mtime +0 | xargs /bin/rm -f
## Now to check the count again.
$ find . -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td\n' | sort | uniq -c
   2275 2020-10-06
```

Not sure why, but I find that using `-exec rm` takes a lot of time while piping `xargs` is quicker.